# Magento Read data from reviews table and display the json

Tags: magento2, database, magento-2.0, review, magento-2.0.4

I want to create a module that **read reviews data from database table in magento and display it in the form of json**. How can i read data from database in magento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve the review collection you can use `\Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Product\Collection` as unfortunately, as of now, Magento 2 does not provide a service layer for the Review module.

You can inject this class in your constructor:

```
protected $_productsFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Product\CollectionFactory $productsFactory,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_productsFactory = $productsFactory;
    ...
}
```

Then you can call the following to get the collection:

```
$collection = $this->_productsFactory->create();
```

If you only want data for one product you can add:

```
$collection->addEntityFilter($productId);
```

Now to encode in JSON you need to inject the `\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data` class in your constructor:

```
protected $_productsFactory;

protected $_jsonHelper;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Product\CollectionFactory $productsFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_productsFactory = $productsFactory;
    $this->_jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
    ...
}
```

Now in order to return a proper JSON I suggest you generate an array from the collection based on the data you need:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($collection as $review) {
    $result[] = ['title' => $review->getTitle(), 'nickname' => $review->getNickname(), 'detail' => $review->getDetail()];
}
$this->jsonHelper->jsonEncode($result);
```

Comment: So u r saying that i cannot access the review_detail table to get the list of reviews??

Comment: @RahulAgrawal no that's not what I'm saying, what I posted will let you retrieve the list of reviews

Comment: @RahulAgrawal I'm saying that you will have to use the model factory instead of the service contracts

Comment: from where do i call the collection part

Comment: and i want the review of all the products

Comment: @RahulAgrawal the code I posted will give you the review of all products, just use it wherever you need it in your module

Comment: I also want to get prodcut id corresponding to each review. is there any getProductId method.

Comment: @RahulAgrawal there is a `getSku` method

Comment: and is there any method other than var_dump to print the output

Comment: @RahulAgrawal if it's in a controller you can do `$this->getResponse()->representJson($this->jsonHelper->jsonEncode($result));`

Comment: is there any getDate method to know the date when the review was posted as i used getCreatedAt method but it is showing prodcut created date

Comment: @RahulAgrawal yes you can use `getCreatedAt`

Comment: it is not correct getCreatedAt returns the product creation date

Comment: @RahulAgrawal sorry `getReviewCreatedAt`

Comment: @RahulAgrawal you're welcome ;) feel free to mark your question as answered so it will benefit for others

Comment: how can i make this module a rest service

Comment: @RahulAgrawal feel free to ask a new question as it'll be hard to answer via the comments