# How to get Product Review based on Product id in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, review, magento2.2

Here I want a Product Review based on Product id.

An object containing something like:

```
review_id
product_image
date
author
price
product_id
rating
product_name
comment
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: Please check my updated answer for get review by both `objectManager` and `Factory method`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is example to get product review by **Product ID**

**By Objectmanager**

```
$productId = '2'; // Product ID
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create("Magento\Catalog\Model\Product")->load($productId);
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$currentStoreId = $storeManager->getStore()->getId();
$rating = $objectManager->get("Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory");

$collection = $rating->create()->addStoreFilter(
            $currentStoreId
        )->addStatusFilter(
            \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
        )->addEntityFilter(
            'product',
            $productId
        )->setDateOrder();

print_r($collection->getData()); //Get all review data of product
```

**By Factory Method**

```
  protected $productRepository; 
  protected $_reviewCollection; 

  public function __construct(
      ...
      \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
      \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $reviewCollection,
      ...
  ) {
      ...
      $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
      $this->_reviewCollection = $reviewCollection;
      ...
  }

  public function getCollection()
  {
    $productId = 2;
    $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
    $collection = $this->_reviewCollection->create()
      ->addStatusFilter(
        \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
      )->addEntityFilter(
      'product',
        $productId
      )->setDateOrder();

      print_r($collection->getData()); //Get all review data of product
  }
```

Comment: Thank you but i also want product image,price and rating?

Comment: You can get product details from `$product` object.

Comment: i implementing above code it work fine.but i don't want to use object manager. i implemented through factory method it will work but not get the rating . i just edit the object manager as a $product_info in which i receive the product information.so how can i get the same data in collection like above code

Comment: @VishnuSalunke Please check my updated answer for get review by both `objectManager` and `Factory method`

Comment: how get reviews from product repository 

should not call reviews factory

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to get Product reviews by Id

```
<?php
$id= 12; // product id
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create("Magento\Catalog\Model\Product")->load($id);
$rating = $objectManager->get("Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory");
$collection = $rating->create()
        ->addStatusFilter(
            \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
        )->addEntityFilter(
            'product',
             $id
        )->setDateOrder();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($collection->getData());
?>
```

Comment: how to get a product image ,price and rating??

Comment: you cab get it from $product object. Like $product->getFinalPrice(); $product->getData('small_image');

Comment: i implementing above code it work fine.but i don't want to use object manager. i implemented through factory method it will work but not get the rating . i just edit the object manager as a $product_info in which i receive the product information.so how can i get the same data in collection like above code.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120576/magento-read-data-from-reviews-table-and-display-the-json